# missing method current_language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I use ExceptionNotification 3.0.1 on Rails 3.2.8 and ruby 1.9.3
I have these lines in production.rb:

```
  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
      :ignore_exceptions => [],
      :ignore_crawlers => %w{Googlebot bingbot},
      :email_prefix => '[Error]',
      :sender_address => 'system@XX.XX',
      :exception_recipients => %w{XX@XX.com},
      :sections => ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.default_sections + %w{system_error}
```

But I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `current_language' for #<ExceptionNotifier::Notifier:
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?